# ListView not scroll smoothly

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have a list view in which i have inflating 3 different type of view, and one type of that view contain horizontal scroll view.
Inside horizontal scroll view i have linear layout,in which i am inflating my custom xml.
All of this working, but scroll of parent list view is not smooth.
When i comment my horizontal scroll view code  then list is scrolling smoothly.
Below is my code :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if(view == null){
         mHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (type == 0) {
         mHolder.mainLinearType1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_linear);
         mHolder.hsv1 = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.hsv);
    }
    if (type == 1) {
    ....
    }
    if (type == 2) {
     ....
    }
    view.setTag(mHolder);
 }
  else{
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 }
 if(type==0){
  mHolder.mainLinearType1.removeAllViews();

  for (int i = 0; i <mList.get(position).getEventList().size(); i++) {
      View additionView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_type1_subitem_view, null,false);

      FrameLayout innerLinnerLayout=(FrameLayout)additionView.findViewById(R.id.frame_view);

      ImageView activityImage = (ImageView) additionView.findViewById(R.id.activity_iv);

      ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) additionView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

      AQueryImageDownloader.loadImage(activityImage, pb, mList.get(position).getEventList().get(i).getEventImagePath(), mContext);

      mHolder.mainLinearType1.addView(innerLinnerLayout);    
    } 
  }
```

I have try a lot but not able to make scrolling properly.
I have also try view pager and horizontal listView. But same issue is occur.
Please help in solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

Below is my listview inside xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/container_ll" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/White">

  <include
       android:id="@+id/header_view" 
       layout="@layout/header_layout" />

<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_view"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:divider="@color/LtGreen"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Google: ListView ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: Try this property in listview in xml file.                                                              android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:animationCache="false"

Comment: i have created ViewHolder class for my list view.when i create ViewHolder for Horizontal scroll view item and then add view to linear layout then it gives error child is allready added to view.Please remove first.

Comment: @shane i try your comment but still same problem.

Comment: make sure listView is not within any scrollable View and also add smoothScrollbar="true [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) can be helpful

Comment: please check my updated question I have added my xml file code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

This basically tells you to use an ASyncTask to handle the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

According to your implementation, you are always inflating the horizontal scrollview for each item, regardless of whether it is a recycled one, so every time Android needs to display an item, it needs to reinflating the horizontal scrollview again, which may explain why the scrolling is not smooth.

You can try to make a `ListView` as part of your item view. This `ListView` will be inflated once when your `convertView == null`, and everytime `getView(position, ...)` of the parent `ListView` is called you refresh the item's `ListView` `Adapter` with values of `mList.get(position).getEventList()`. Since we only swap data of a recycled view, my guess is that it will not affect scrolling much.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (view == null) {
         mHolder = new ViewHolder();
      if (type == 0) {
           mHolder.mainLinearType1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_linear);
           mHolder.hsv1 = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.hsv);
           mHolder.listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.frame_view); // assume this is your ListView
      }
      if (type == 1) {
      ....
      }
      if (type == 2) {
       ....
      }
      view.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    if (type==0) {
      mHolder.mainLinearType1.removeAllViews();
      mHolder.listView.setAdapter(new Adapter() {
        // override adapter with implementation that returns items from mList.get(position).getEventList()
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I am not getting,can you please explain how to inflate adapter for HorizontalScrollView, from my listview row.